# How do I recover deleted files using git hub in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I've been using GIT with Visual Studio 2019.  I accidentally deleted several files and committed that delete.  How can I recover those files?

I can view the history via Visual Studio and find the commit where I deleted those files.  I tried Revert, Reset - Keep Changes, and Reset - Delete Changes.  My files did not come back.

What do I have to do to recover those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the commit which deleted the files and revert it, then commit that revert!

In a shell, this would be `git log` to see the log of commits, and then `git revert aaaaaa` where `aaaaaa` is the offending commit.

[`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) without other args *unstages* commits

Comment: That worked! My issue was I wasn't committing the revert.  After I did it I did a pull from master since I assumed the revert applied automatically.

Comment: You are my savior! I accidentally deleted the whole project in a commit.

Answer (score 0):

> I can view the history via Visual Studio and find the commit where I deleted those files. I tried ... Reset - Keep Changes, and Reset - Delete Changes. My files did not come back."

No, because that's the wrong commit. That's the commit *where you deleted the files*. That means the files are *not in the commit*. That is what delete means.

The last commit *containing* the files is the *previous* commit.

You could use `git checkout` to extract each of those files by name from that commit. The syntax is

```
git checkout SHA -- path/to/file
```

Keep in mind that the recovered files will now be in your worktree but not in your next commit until you `git add` them.